# How to print this pattern? I cannot get the logic for eliminating the middle part

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Write a program that asks the user for an input `n` (assume that the user enters a positive integer) and prints only the boundaries of the triangle using asterisks `'*'` of height `n`.

For example if the user enters 6 then the height of the triangle should be 6 as shown below and there should be no spaces between the asterisks on the top
line:

```
******
*   *
*  *
* *
**
*
```

I cannot understand how to print the part between top and end of pattern? This is my code:

```
n = int(input("Enter a positive integer value: "))
for i in range (n, 0, -1):
    print ("*" * i)
```

The `for` loop is for printing the reverse asterisks triangle. Obstacle is to print the middle part.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In every iteration of the `for` loop You print one line of the pattern and it's length is `i`. So, in the first and the last line of the pattern You will have `"*" * i`.
In every other line of the pattern you have to print one `*` at start of the line, one `*` at the end, and `(i - 2)` spaces in the middle because 2 stars were already printed out, which results in `"*" + (" " * (i - 2)) + "*"`. After combining that two cases, we get the following code:

```
n = int(input("Enter a positive integer value: "))
for i in range(n, 0, -1):
    if i == 1 or i == n:   
        print("*" * i)
    else:
        print("*" + (" " * (i - 2)) + "*")
```

Comment: I can't understand the last else part. Can you please explain?

Comment: Well in the middle of the pattern you have to print one `*` at start of the line, one `*` at the end, and `(i-2)` spaces at the middle because 2 stars were already printed out. That's pretty much all.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please accept the answer with green check mark next to it, if You feel that it solved Your issue.

Comment: It would be a good idea to [edit] your additional explanation into the answer itself, so that it's more obvious to future readers. In general, code-only answers are harder to generalise than ones where these is some explanation of the problem-solving followed to produce this code.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the suggestion, I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 10):

Try the following, it avoids using an `if` statement within the `for` loop:

```
n = int(input("Enter a positive integer value: "))
print('*' * n)

for i in range (n-3, -1, -1):
    print ("*{}*".format(' ' * i))

print('*')
```

For 6, you will get the following output:

```
******
*   *
*  *
* *
**
*
```

You could also handle the special case of `1` as follows:

```
n = int(input("Enter a positive integer value: "))

if n == 1:
    print '*'
else:
    print('*' * n)

    for i in range (n-3, -1, -1):
        print ("*{}*".format(' ' * i))

    print('*')
```

Answer (score 5):

Put different conditions for different ways of printing.

Using ternary operator, you can make it a one line code:

```
n = int(input("Enter a positive integer value: "))
for i in range (n, 0, -1):
    print ("*" * i if i == n or i == 1 else "*" + " " * (i - 2) + "*")
```

Notice that you only have *two* ways of printing.

The trick is to:

Note that you actually print continuously when `i == n or i == 1`:

```
******
*
```

But otherwise you give spaces as many as `(i - 2)`

```
*   * #for 5, 3 spaces
*  *  #for 4, 2 spaces
* *   #for 3, 1 space
**    #for 2, 0 space
```

(Note: `**` can be classified as both cases, nevertheless)

And so you can make 1 line statement to accomplish it.

**Edit:**

Or, as [Bakuriu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/510937/bakuriu) suggested in the comment, you could exploit the Python boolean evaluation result as 1 when true and 0 when false to print it without ternary operator like this:

```
n = int(input("Enter a positive integer value: "))
for i in range (n, 0, -1):
    print('*' + '*'[i==n]*(i-2) + '*' * (i>1))
```

Comment: Even a shorter one: `print('*'+' *'[i==n]*(i-2)+'*'*(i>1))`

Comment: @Bakuriu wow! I can't believe that you can *find* one which is *that* short. But you are right... it is even shorter! ;)

Comment: @Bakuriu answer changed. That's definitely worth included. ;)

Comment: Why the emphasis on making the code short? This isn't code golf. [Tony Babarino's code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35547354/157957) is much clearer than either of these.

Comment: @IMSoP coming from C and C# background, it is just my little preferred style, I believe. But obviously that style cannot be transferred directly to Python... If it is about the clarity / readibility of the code, then yes, Tony Babariono's code is better. The reason why I add Bakuriu code on top of my answer is because it happens to fit with my preference... and I appreciate it.. :)

Comment: I would say regardless of language, readability always trumps conciseness; but, yes, that is a matter of taste to some extent.

Answer (score 3):

A for loop would be more compact, but a while loop is perhaps simpler if you aren't used to Python's loops

```
print('*'*n)
num_spaces = n - 3 # bounded by two stars, and one char shorter
while num_spaces >= 0:
    print('*' + ' '*num_spaces + '*')
    num_spaces = num_spaces - 1
if n > 1: # Don't need another asterisk for 1
    print('*')
```

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to others...just using rjust() to make the spaces in the middle.

```
def print_a_triangle(n):
    print("*" * (n+3))
    for i in range(n):
        print("{}{}{}".format("*", str(" ").rjust(n-i), "*"))

    print("*")

print_a_triangle(6)

*********
*      *
*     *
*    *
*   *
*  *
* *
*
```